# restfb: encountering 504 while uploading video sized 950 mb

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, restfb

Using restfb-1.6.12

Creating client as:

```
facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, new CustomWebRequestor(), new DefaultJsonMapper());
```

In CustomWebRequestor, customizeConnection() is overridden and following is specified:

```
connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(5242880);
```

Uploading video as:

```
facebookClient.publish("me/videos", FacebookType.class, BinaryAttachment.with(mediaFileName, mediaFileStream), Parameter.with("description", msg), Parameter.with("target_id", "me"), Parameter.with("metadata", 1));
```

Encountering following:

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookNetworkException: A network error occurred while trying to communicate with Facebook: Facebook request failed (HTTP status code 504)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:625)
```

Upload happens as I can find the video on Facebook, but the reponse received from API doesn't tell me so. API works for videos of lesser size, like 400-500 MB. Recent change log doesn't mention any change around this either. Some help please.

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Yeah, probably. Trying to tweak the API a little for now. If that doesn't work, will file a bug. Thought I'd ask here first if somebody knew something about this.

Comment: For reference: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/791781120839901/

Comment: Facebook have fixed the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook fixed the problem under bug developers.facebook.com/bugs/791781120839901

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/videos#publish

There, Facebook states that

> Videos must be encoded as `multipart/form-data` and published to
>   `graph-video.facebook.com` instead of the regular Graph API URL.

Also, other rules are

> The aspect ratio of the video must be between 9x16 and 16x9, and the
>   video cannot exceed 1024MB or 180 minutes in length

Does RestFB use the correct endpoint?

Comment: The URL is proper. Checked that. About endpoint, that is correct too as videos smaller in size are getting uploaded and the response we receive from Facebook in this case is a 504 and nothing else. The strange thing is I can see the video on Facebook timeline.

Comment: Then I guess you should file a bug, as @WizKid recommended as well